# Tecplot, Python or Vim assistance: How can I write out an image (PNG, JPEG) file using the current working directory as the name?

Tags: python, vim

I'm working in the following directory structure as listed below:

```
/home/project/airplane/mach1p0 

/home/project/airplane/mach1p1 

/home/project/airplane/mach1p2
```

.
. 
`/home/project/airplane/machXpX` (you get the idea, there are many files!)

I have a Tecplot macro that reads in data and then simply writes out an image. The output at the moment is hard coded as image.png and it would be preferable if it was written out based on the name of the current working directory, for example mach1p0.png

Is there a way I can some how incorporate the working directory in the name of the PNG using either Python, Vim, or Tecplot?

In my shell script I'm using the following command:

```
mv image.png $1.png
```

where $1 is a variable (machxpx) defined in another file. This approach requires me to have another file which has to contain a list of variables which makes this process inefficient.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how can you use vim in this scenario ...
You can try in your shell script, replace the `$1` by `${PWD##*/}`

This will get the name of current directory.

Hope I got you right.